# Mathematical constrained optimization in R

Tags: r, mathematical-optimization, algebra

I have a mathematical optimization which I wish to solve in `R` consider this system/problem:

[image]

**How Can I solve this problem in R?**

In this model `Budget`, `p_l` for all `l` and `mu_target` are fixed constants while `mu`is a given m-dimensional vector and `R` is a given n by m  matrix.

I have looked into `constrOptim` and `lp` but I don't have the imagination to implement the constraints

Those functions require that I have a "constraint" matrix but my problem is that I simply don't know how to design that constraint matrix. There are not many examples with decision variables on both sides of the equations.

Comment: I believe this is an LP, so an LP solver would be more appropriate.

Comment: Can you suggest one and give an example on how to program my constraints?

Comment: A constraint like `x>=y` can be transformed into `x-y>=0`. So variables on the right can easily be moved to the left. You may want discuss this with your teacher.

Comment: I know. But there is a LONG way from this to actually programming a the constraints as required in in LP. It is a private project I am doing and not a school assignment

Answer (score 0):

Have a look on the nloptr package. It has quite extensive documentation with examples. Lots of algorithms to choose from, depending what problem you are trying to resolve.

[NLoptr link](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/nloptr/nloptr.pdf)